# 2 ui-view in the same page angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I need to have 3 elements in a same view and I do not know how to do it, I have my ui-view = 'main' or I can display my menu but I do not know how to display the template Of the selected menu in the same view

this is my routing

```
routeApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider){

$stateProvider
    .state("connexion", {
        url: "/connexion",
        templateUrl: 'Template/connexion.html',
        controller: 'PostController'
    })
    .state("accueil", {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'Template/connexion.html',
        controller: 'PostController'
    })
    .state('agenda', {

        url: "/agenda",
        views: {

            // for column two, we'll define a separate controller
            '': {

                templateUrl: 'Template/agenda.html',
                controller: 'customersCtrl',
                resolve:{
                    "check":function($cookies,$location){   //function to be resolved, accessFac and $location Injected

                        // console.log($cookies.get('user'));
                        if ($cookies.get('user')){    //check if the user has permission -- This happens before the page loads

                            // $cookies.remove('user');

                        }else{
                            $location.path('/');                //redirect user to home if it does not have permission.
                            alert("Vous devez vous connecter pour acceder a cette page");
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            'main':{

                url: "/menu",
                templateUrl: 'Template/menuAddAgenda.html'

               /* //i want to put here
                ("bar", {

                    url: "/bar",
                    templateUrl: 'Template/bar.html'
                })

                ("foo", {

                url: "/bar",
                templateUrl: 'Template/foo.html'
                })
                */
            }
        }

    })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

})

this is my modal code

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">

<div class="row">
    <div class="span12 ui-view-container">
        <div class="well" ui-view="main"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>
```

and this my code menu

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Quick Start</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="foo">Route 1</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="bar">Route 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My menu displays correctly but I do not know how to set the route with my ui-sref To be displayed in the same view

if some one can help me

thans in advance

Comment: no body can help me ?